# Probability Laws - Probability equations

Tags: probability

> Given that $P(A) = 0.35$, $P(B) = 0.45$ and $P(A\cap B)=0.13$ 
>
>  find (a) $P(A \cup B)$ 
> (b) $P(A'|B')$
>
>  (c)  The event C has $P(C) = 0.2$. The events A and C are mutually exclusive and the events B and C are independent. Find $P(B \cap C)$

**I have solved part (a) and (b)**. But I included them for context. I am unsure if the introduction of probability the event C will change the probabilities of event A and B. Well we are told that B and C are independent, so I guess we know that these events don't influence each other. But how do we know the introduction of event C doesn't reduce the probability of event A occuring.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram and all will be clear.

Comment: I have still not clear

Comment: Did you draw a Venn diagram... yes or no?

Comment: You're told $A$ and $C$ are *mutually exclusive*. That tells you exactly how $C$ influences $A$. [Do you know what "mutually exclusive" means?]

Comment: Care to engage with the comments and answers that have been posted, w3l271?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is noncommunicative.

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove first the following identity:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

In order to do so, notice that $A\cup B = (A\backslash B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\backslash A)$. Hence one gets:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) & = \textbf{P}(A\backslash B) + \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(B\backslash A)\\\\
& = \textbf{P}(A\cap B^{c}) + \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(B\cap A^{c})\\\\
& = (\textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)) + \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + (\textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B))\\\\
& = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)
\end{align*}
and we are done. Therefore the answer to the first question is:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) = 0.35 + 0.45 - 0.13 = 0.67
\end{align*}

As to the second question, one concludes that:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A^{c}|B^{c}) & = \frac{\textbf{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c})}{\textbf{P}(B^{c})} = \frac{\textbf{P}((A\cup B)^{c})}{1 - \textbf{P}(B)} = \frac{1 - \textbf{P}(A\cup B)}{1 - \textbf{P}(B)} = \frac{1 - 0.67}{1 - 0.45} = \frac{0.33}{0.55} = \frac{3}{5} = 0.6
\end{align*}

Finally, the last question can be handled as follows:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(B\cap C) = \textbf{P}(B)\textbf{P}(C) = 0.45\times 0.2 = 0.09
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> But how do we know the introduction of event C doesn't reduce the probability of event A occurring.

Event C has not been created; it has always been an event in the probability space.

The introduction is just that its probability *and relations* to the other events has been described, which does not alter the already known facts.

---

In any case, when asked about the measure of $B\cap C$, all you need to know is the probabilities of $B$ and $C$ and that *they are independent*.

You will not need to know that $A$ and $C$ are *mutually exclusive* until you are similarly asked about the union or intersection of $A$ and $C$.